# Restart VMs in scale set in AKS Node Pool

Tags: python, kubernetes, azure-aks, chaos, azure-resource-graph

I have a kubernetes cluster with node pools and as a part of Chaos Engineering Initiative,I need to restart the VM. Is there any code for the same using azure resource graph?

Answer (score 6):

When the AKS nodes is a scale set. Then you need to find the node resource group, the scale set name, and the instance-id that you want to restart. And then restart the instance. Here are the CLI commands:

```
# get the AKS node resource group name
az aks show -g groupName -n aksName --query nodeResourceGroup

# get the scale set info and all the instance id
az vmss list -g nodeGroupName --query [].name
az vmss list-instances -g nodeGroupName -n vmssName -o table

# restart the instance with the instance Id
az vmss restart -g nodeGroupName -n vmssName --instance-ids n
```

If you do it in the Azure portal, the same steps but it's easier to achieve.

Comment: how do it using az graph query?

Comment: @Batman22 I'm afraid not. The command `az graph query` only can get the scale set, cannot get the instance Id for you.

Comment: We did it using instance id...I will post the answer soon. thank!

Comment: @Batman22 Why you will post an answer? My answer does not solve your problem? If it solves your issue, what you need to do is accept it.

Comment: @Batman22 What's the reason you do not accept the answer when it helps you solve the problem? It's not difficult to do it!

Comment: the answer is different i will post it soon. thanks!

Comment: I upvoted it but will post a python code for doing the same since i asked specifically for the way to do it with code

Comment: @Batman22 Where do you say you need to do it in python in the question? No one will guess what you need if you do not elaborate on it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Gremlin on your AKS cluster. Here is an in-depth tutorial that I wrote: https://www.gremlin.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-gremlin-with-kubernetes/

When practicing Chaos Engineering on a kubernetes cluster it's important to control the blast radius of your attacks - e.g. how many VMs will you restart? Do you want to restart the whole VM or just 1 or more pods on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Chaos toolkit already has the code for fetching vms from scaleset. The code can be checked at https://github.com/chaostoolkit-incubator/chaostoolkit-azure/blob/master/chaosazure/vmss/fetcher.py.